# How to make a good profile view

Tags: iphone

I've created a vue called profile in wich I put labels that I've named (frist name, family name,adress,etc etc) and for each label there is a textield,
so my idea is to display on the textfield by default for example : enter your first name, enter your family name etc etc, so that once we click on the textfield , the keyboard get displayed.
Is there anybody who can help please ??

Answer (score 1):

my opinion is use tableview for get input from the user

use this tableviewcell to tableview which will look awesome follow this tutorial

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/01/04/elctextfieldcell-a-useful-tableviewcell-for-forms/

Comment: UITableView/Controller is the way to go - anything else is pure hassle.